# How to enable HTML validation for a disabled HTML input text field

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

How can I enable HTML validation for a disabled HTML input text field?

Here is my code:

```
<!--
<?php
my php code here...
?>
-->


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<form action="">
    
<select name="0" required="" >
    <option name="1" value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option name="2" value="2"> 2 </option>
</select><br>  
<!--choosing or changing above select box will assign value to input box "5" (using javascript and php db)-->    
    
<input name="3" type="text" required="" ><br>
<input name="4" type="text" disabled="" ><br>
<input name="5" type="text" required="" disabled=""><br>
<input type="submit" >
</form>
</html>
 <!-- i want to force user to choose select box before submiting form -->
```

I want the input field "5" to not be empty, and I don't want the user to edit the field manually, either.

Instead, when the user selects or chooses an item in dropbox, my JS and PHP will automatically assign a value to input field "5".

If the user submits the form without selecting an item from the dropbox, the dropbox value will be the default value, but since user hasn't clicked the dropbox, the JS will not work and no value will be assigned to input field "5", so the form will post empty or no value for input field "5".

**Since input field "5" is set to `disabled=""`, HTML validation is not working**

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9e7s2ova) (click the submit button to see that input field "5" is not validating)

Comment: Why not just make the select box required?

Comment: ...or add the default value to the box before you start?

Comment: Make the select box required and give it an empty value, so if the user submits without changing it it wont validate

Comment: Hi, @Len_D, thank you. already assigned required="" select box.  but there will a default value in select box already, so required="" validation will not work.

Comment: Why not [`readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.readonly) instead of `disabled`?

Comment: readonly also not works :( @robertc

Comment: why not make input 5 a hidden box then the user never knows it is there or can edit it.

Comment: @Jim , actually, i want to show the field to user. user need to know what is the value in that field, but i don't want him to change it.

Comment: If you make the default an empty string, using something like this, 
<option value="">Please select</option>
then required would work.

Comment: @AthulAK then as suggested, make the field read only and put a default value in the field.  Then if the select box still is not clicked it will at least have a value

Comment: I do exactly what you are trying to do using Jquery. I have a select box, required, and a text field, read-only. As soon as the user selects something, the text box is populated with the selected value and displays to the user. Is that essentially what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the option "Select" to the dropbox(name="0") as below mentioned code. so that you can validate the dropbox.

```
<select name="0" required= >
  <option name="1" value="">Select</option>
  <option name="1" value="1"> 1 </option>
  <option name="2" value="2"> 2 </option>
</select>
```

Or you can add the default value to the input(name="4") as like below.

```
<input name="5" type="text" required="" disabled="" value="1"><br>
```

Comment: as eskimo and Len_D said in question's comments... this works, i prefer to use <option name="a" value="">Select</option> in select box, so validation for select box works, and user forced to choose any value in dropbox! thank you.